# Lollipop boots only in recovery

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, boot-loop

I am using a Lenovo p70 phone with custom aosp 5.1 arm64 based rom! I am using TWRP recovery. Until today i had no problems with the recovery. 
Today i rebooted my phone in recovery by typing `reboot recovery` in terminal emulator. Now everytime i try to boot my phone it boots only in recovery.
So now i can't boot my android os anymore.

P.S It also boots in recovery when i use `adb shell reboot` or `adb shell reboot recovery`. `adb shell reboot bootloader` still works as it intended.

Can anyone help?

P.S2 I found a file which tries to fix this problem, but targets android ics so i don't think it will help.

Comment: Did you try resetting the phone?

Comment: @esQmo what do you mean by resetting? Wiping data, cache? I plan to restore a backup but i have no physical access to the drive with my backup at the moment.

Comment: Yes this may help.

Comment: Can you wipe the cache partition?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab  I already wiped cache and dalvik-cache but there is no result.

Comment: Can you wipe the cache partition?